# C# Linked Lists (adding an element to a defined position)

Tags: c#

Our teacher asked us to implement the class `LinkedList`. I was able to implement everything he asked for. But he gave us a bonus question that I was not able to solving.

He asked us to implement this fonction:

```
public void add(float x, int pos)
{
  // Add x at the position pos, pos = 0 refer to the first element.
}
```

He also demanded that his code verifies the following UnitTest:

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    private MyList l;

    public UnitTest1()
    {
        l = new MyList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            l.add(i * i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            l.add(i * i);
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestAdd()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(l.count(), 20);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestGet()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(l.get(i), (9 - i) * (9 - i));
        }
        for (int i = 10; i < 20; ++i)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(l.get(i), (19 - i) * (19 - i));
        }
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFind()
    {
        int k;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
            {
                if (k * k == i)
                {
                    Assert.AreEqual(l.find(i), true);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (k == 10)
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(l.find(i), false);
            }
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestStats()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(l.max(), 81);
        float s = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            s += i * i + i * i;
        }
        Assert.AreEqual(l.sum(), s);
        Assert.AreEqual(l.average(), s / 20);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestCountValue()
    {
        MyList l1 = new MyList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            l1.add(i);
            l1.add(i * i);
        }
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(-1), 0);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(0), 2);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(1), 2);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(2), 1);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(3), 1);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(4), 2);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(5), 1);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(6), 1);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(7), 1);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(8), 1);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(9), 2);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(10), 0);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(16), 1);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestRemoveFirst()
    {
        MyList l1 = new MyList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            l1.add(i);
            l1.add(i * i);
        }
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(81), 1);
        l1.removeFirst();
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(), 19);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(81), 0);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(-1), 0);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(0), 2);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(1), 2);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(2), 1);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(3), 1);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(4), 2);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(5), 1);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(6), 1);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(7), 1);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(8), 1);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(9), 2);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(10), 0);
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.count(16), 1);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestInsert()
    {
        MyList l1 = new MyList();
        for (int i = 9; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            l1.add(i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
        {
            l1.add(i, 2 * i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(l1.get(2 * i), i, "i=" + i);
            Assert.AreEqual(l1.get(2 * i + 1), i);
        }
        Assert.AreEqual(l1.get(20), 10);
    }
}
```

That's what I was capable of:

```
public class MyList
{
    class Element
    {
        public float value;
        public Element next;
    }

    Element first;

    public MyList()
    {
        first = null;
    }

    public void add(float x)
    {
        Element e = new Element();
        e.value = x;
        e.next = first;
        first = e;
    }
    public float get(int i)
    {
        if (first == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Empty list... no elements inside");
        }

        Element tmp = first;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
            tmp = tmp.next;
            if (tmp == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("...");
            }
        }

        return tmp.value;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        Element e = first;
        while (e != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.value);
            e = e.next;
        }
    }

    public bool find(float x)
    {
        Element e = first;
        while (e != null)
        {
            if (e.value == x)
            {
                return true;
            }
            e = e.next;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public float max()
    {
        float G = 0;
        for (Element e = first; e != null; e = e.next)
        {
            if (e.value > G)
            {
                G = e.value;
            }
        }

        return G;
    }

    public int count()
    {
        Element e = first;
        int c = 0;
        while (e != null)
        {
            c++;
            e = e.next;
        }

        return c;
    }

    public int count(float x)
    {
        int c = 0;
        for (Element e = first; e != null; e = e.next)
        {
            if (e.value == x)
            {
                c++;
            }
        }

        return c;
    }

    public float sum()
    {
        float S = 0;
        for (Element e = first; e != null; e = e.next)
        {
            S += e.value;
        }

        return S;
    }

    public float average()
    {
        return sum() / count();
    }

    public void removeFirst()
    {
        Element e = first;
        first = e.next;
    }

    public void add(float x, int pos)
    {
        //I have absolutely no idea how to implement this fonction.
    }
}
```

Comment: ...are you asking us to do this work for you so that you can receive class credit for this work?

Comment: What is the actual problem where you stuck?

Comment: Not at all it's a bonus question there is no grade on it. It's some kind of challenge. And i'm curious on knowing the answer. I tried to take example on the way to insert an element in an array but lists and arrays work in very different ways when it's about removing/adding elements to them.

Comment: I imagine that anyone who coded `find(i)` and `add(x)` should have no issue combining the two to complete the `add(i,x)` functionality.

Comment: And I'm not asking for the solution. Any tips/advises/clues... would do :x

Comment: @GeorgesRidgmont, this isnt really what stack is for. We can help you with homework as per point three, in this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. However, as its only a bonus question and youre asking for tips on how to do it, its not really a question for this site and therefore I vote to close.

Comment: So the problem is that it's a bonus a question... thank you for your honesty. Anyway if this post is bothering you for dunno what reason I don't have a problem for it to be closed. I'll have to ask my teacher for the solution. Thank you.

Comment: No, its not that its a bonus question, the bigger issue is that youre asking for tips on how to do it rather than having tried and failed and having a  problem we can replicate

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @GeorgesRidgmont Welcome to Stack Overflow! :D

Comment: Welcome to SO indeed. People need to get off their high horse. It's obvious what this guy is asking.. help on implementing a method for add(). We all started somewhere. Comments that don't offer anything constructive are no better than the questions in which you feel are too generic.

Answer (score 0):

It will be similar to the code in the get() method.

Break your problem down into smaller problems

- Does pos = 0?

  - if so, create a new root and point it to the old root
  - if not, loop (pos) times and create a new element. Then set the next property of the new element to the next property of the current element. Set the current element next property to your new element

.

```
public void add(float x, int pos)
{
    if(pos == 0)
    {
        // create a new root and point the new root to the existing root
    }
    else
    {
        Element tmp = first;
        for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
        {
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }

        // create new element
        // set new element next property to tmp.next
        // set tmp.next to new element
    }
}
```